# Use for-loop index inside variable

Tags: java, for-loop

I have the following for loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
    if (someVariable==anotherVariable)
        jPanel(i).remove(anElement);
}
```

I would like to use the for loop to iterate through the JPanels I have, and remove a certain elements from all of them, my jPanels are named jPanel0, jPanel1,jPanel2....jPanel5

I know the above code doesn't work and I have no idea how to do it. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating multiple variables named `jPanel0`, `jPanel1`... you should create an array of `JPanel[] panels;`. Then you can access a specific panel with `panels[i]` in your loop.